# What causes session/forms authentication timeouts in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session-timeout, formsauthentication

Can somebody please let me know what are the reasons for your authentication to die suddenly, even when you are working on an application without any idle time?  Both with and without AJAX calls.  And what are the different reasons for getting a 302 redirect from an MVC3 application to the Logon page.
   Been struggling with an issue with timeouts that happen at random.  Sometimes within a few minutes of login to the application and sometimes you can go for hours (with/without idle time) without being thrown out.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the answer on this question.  This has resolve my issue with redirect loops. 
[IIS Session timeout and Forms Authentication loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616247/iis-session-timeout-and-forms-authentication-loop)