# How do I debug AuthorizeAttribute and FormsAuthentication calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, authorize-attribute

I am having crazy problems with Forms Authentication, with the AuthorizeAttribute, and 302 redirect loops.  I need to find out what is going on. Is there anyway I can debug Forms Authentication and the AuthorizeAttribute?

Just some more details, in case it is important:

1. I am using custom membership provider and role provider.  I have the correct methods implemented and doing the reading for User/Roles from my custom database tables.
2. I have the following in my `web.config` to point to my custom providers:

   ```
   <membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
       <providers>
           <clear />
           <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="Domain.Entities.Security.MyMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MyDB" MinRequiredPasswordLength="8" MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters="0" applicationName="My App Name" />
       </providers>
   </membership>
   <profile enabled="false">
       <providers>
           <clear />
       </providers>
   </profile>
   <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider" cookieTimeout="2800" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
       <providers>
           <clear />
           <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="Domain.Entities.Security.MyRoleProvider" connectionStringName="MyDB" applicationName="/" />
       </providers>
   </roleManager>
   ```
3. Some of my controller/actions are 'open'.  Some of them have the 'Authorize[Roles="admin"]' and similar.
4. Sometimes I can work on the application for hours without anything happening. Sometimes I hit a 302 redirect loop soon after I login and then I try to go into one of the other pages. Once that happens, I cannot even go into the top level path without it going into a 302 redirect loop sometimes.

Any directions, any pointers, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anybody?  Any kind of guidance on this at all?  I've been staring at it so long, not sure where to look next.  Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see the answer in the question linked.  This was the resolution to the redirect loop problem. 
[IIS Session timeout and Forms Authentication loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616247/iis-session-timeout-and-forms-authentication-loop)