# The page isn't redirecting properly when use Roles in Aothorizee

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, identity

I have this Action Method , And I use Authorize with Roles like as :

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "member")]
public virtual ActionResult Profile()
{
...
}
```

And I have this Method  For Login and add cooki:

```
 SetAuthCookie(loginVM.UserName, RoleOfTheMember.Name, loginVM.RememberMe);
```

> RoleOfTheMember.Name has value :"Member"

And this SetAutoCooki :

```
private void SetAuthCookie(string memberName, string roleofMember, bool presistantCookie)
    {
        var timeout = presistantCookie ? FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes : 30;

        var now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
        var expirationTimeSapne = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout);

        var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,memberName,now,now.Add(expirationTimeSapne),presistantCookie,roleofMember,FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
            );

        var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
            Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
        };

        if (FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain != null)
        {
            authCookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
        }

        if (presistantCookie)
            authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);

        Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
    }
```

But when Call This Action I getting This ERROR By Browser :

```
The page isn't redirecting properly
```

Whats A problems ?

**I don't use any RoleProvider .** Do I use Implement Role Provider?

Comment: This **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616247/iis-session-timeout-and-forms-authentication-loop)** might help you..

Comment: no its not help me .